# How can I get the height and width of image having a Base64 string source?

Tags: image, reactjs, base64, size

I have a Base64 string in my [Redux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redux_(JavaScript_library)) store, and I want to get the height and width of that image. Is it possible? How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example:

```js
var base64string ="data:image/png;base64,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"

var img = document.createElement("img")
img.setAttribute("src", base64string)
setTimeout(function(){
   console.log(img.height, img.width);
}, 0)
```

Create an *img* from a Base64-encoded string and then set the Base64-encoded string as its `src`.

Comment: the result of that is  0,0 ... Why? and how can i fix it?

Comment: @MetaCode Updated the answer, can you check now?

Comment: But, what happen if the image load in 2 seconds for example?